# How much memory does a Hashtable use?

Tags: java, hashtable, memory-management

In Java, if I create a `Hashtable<K, V>` and put N elements in it, how much memory will it occupy? If it's implementation dependent, what would be a good "guess"?

Comment: It's probably going to be dominated by the size of your key and value objects (except for small maps).

Comment: I've added a precise calculation, although it may vary with the VM. 

That is not always true.  With very small keys and values (say, with wrapper objects for primitives) the size of the Entry objects may dominate the size of the hashmap/hashtable (internally they are the same).  This can also happen if multiple values are references to the same object instance.  

If you're using a lot of primitive objects as keys or values, look into the Trove library.  It is faster and more memory efficient for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit; **Oh geez, I'm an idiot, I gave info for HashMap, not HashTable.  However, after checking, the implementations are identical for memory purposes.**

This is dependent on your VM's internal memory setup (packing of items, 32 bit or 64 bit pointers, and word alignment/size) and is not specified by java.

Basic info on estimating memory use can be found [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml).

You can estimate it like so:

- On 32-bit VMs, a pointer is 4 bytes, on 64-bit VMs, it is 8 bytes.
- Object overhead is 8 bytes of memory (for an empty object, containing nothing)
- Objects are padded to a size that is a multiple of 8 bytes (ugh).
- There is a small, constant overhead for each hashmap: one float, 3 ints, plus object overhead.
- There is an array of slots, some of which will have entries, some of which will be reserved for new ones.  The ratio of filled slots to total slots is NO MORE THAN the specified load factor in the constructor.
- The slot array requires one object overhead, plus one int for size, plus one pointer for every slot, to indicate the object stored.
- The number of slots is generally 1.3 to 2 times more than the number of stored mappings, at default load factor of 0.75, but may be less than this, depending on hash collisions.
- Every stored mapping requires an entry object.  This requires one object overhead, 3 pointers, plus the stored key and value objects, plus an integer.

**So, putting it together (for 32/64 bit Sun HotSpot JVM):
HashMap needs 24 bytes (itself, primtive fields) + 12 bytes (slot array constant) + 4 or 8 bytes per slot + 24/40 bytes per entry + key object size + value object size + padding each object to multiple of 8 bytes**

**OR, roughly (at most default settings, not guaranteed to be precise):**

- **On 32-bit JVM: 36 bytes + 32 bytes/mapping + keys & values**
- **On 64-bit JVM: 36 bytes + 56 bytes/mapping + keys & values**

Note: this needs more checking, it might need 12 bytes for object overhead on 64-bit VM.
I'm not sure about nulls -- pointers for nulls may be compressed somehow.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to estimate. I would read this first:
http://www.codeinstructions.com/2008/12/java-objects-memory-structure.html

Just use the sunjdk tools to figure out the size of K, V and

jmap -histo [pid]

num     #instances         #bytes  class name

1:        126170       19671768  MyKClass

2:        126170       14392544  MyVClass

3:             1         200000  MyHashtable

Also you may want to use HashMap instead of Hashtable if you do not need synchronization.