# Java object creation and memory size

Tags: java, memory, allocation

I am trying understand about the size that a Java object will be allocated with when created using a **new** operator.

Consider that i am creating a class

```
public class NewClass {

    NewClass() { }

}
```

when i create an instance of `NewClass` using `NewClass nc = new NewClass();`. what is the size of the `NewClass` that gets created in the heap?

~ Jegan

Answer (score 9):

Profiling is the best way, but you can get a good estimate like so:

8 bytes per object (bare overhead), plus fields.

- Primitive Fields: as listed in Java.  Note: booleans need 1 full byte.
- Object fields: 1 pointer (4 bytes on 32-bit VM, 8 on 64-bit), plus size of object itself (if not a reference to a preexisting object)
- Arrays: 4 bytes + object/primitives for elements
- Strings: far, far too much.  IIRC, 24 bytes + 2 bytes/character. Might be more.

The final result is increased to the nearest multiple of 8 bytes.

See also my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425221/how-much-memory-does-a-hashtable-use) for how to calculate memory use on a more complex object.  Note: these rules may vary with VMs, and may change as newer versions of the VM come out.  My estimate only applies to the Sun JVM, although I suspect IBM's results will be similar.

Comment: Note that "size of object itself" may not be applicable if you're referencing objects that already exist. Same goes for the array elements.

Comment: I thought that was assumed, but fair enough -- I added a couple qualifiers to make it clear under what conditions this estimate applies.

Comment: I would have said the bare overhead is 16 bytes. (On 64-bit JVMs at least)

Comment: @Peter:  I think you're right (I read it was 2 machine words in one place), but can you cite a source to confirm that?

Comment: Note for arrays of arrays you take the hit twice, e.g. double[3][2] is 64 bytes, whilst double[6] is only 52 bytes. Languages with multi-dimensional array support, e.g. C#, don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a profiler to measure this. You may use [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) profilers for this.